# How can I edit the HTML source code of an email in Outlook 2010 without any add-ins?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, html

I need to be able to make HTML custom emails with div tags, formatting, and such, and I need to be able to send it with Outlook 2010.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is the solution for Outlook 2010/2013, without any plug-in but with Notepad++:

1. Open Notepad++, create a new file and save it in a temporary folder with a `.html` extension.
2. Click on Run > Send via Outlook; this opens a mail with your HTML code.

Beware that not using a `.html` extension, such as `.txt`, might create a new email with an attachment, rather than a new HTML formatted message.

Note the following image shows the French language translation of Notepad++. In English use the "Run" menu.
[image: Send via outlook]

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Wow! Absolutely love this solution!

Comment: Execution (Fr) = Run (Eng)

Comment: thank you @JohnnyBizzle for english helping, Altough submenu is in english, main menu remains in french ...

Comment: OK well this sucks.  They completely removed this options from notepad++.  What a shame.  https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3579#issuecomment-488686697

Comment: weird, I still have it and according to the version info my build is from Jan 12th, 2020

Comment: Where is `Run`? Where is `Send`?

Comment: Wish I could upvote 100x. Thanks! The feature is STILL THERE

Answer (score 17):

I'm running Outlook 2007, not 2010, but the instructions [here](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/html-forum/115727-html-email-outlook-2007-a.html#post884677) worked for me:

> Save the File as an HTML file,
>
> Create a new message in Outlook 07 and go to Insert > and click on the
>   Attach File (Paperclip Icon) Your browser will pop up, When you select
>   the HTML file the INSERT button to the bottom right will activate -
>   but to the right of the button there will be a down arrow, click on
>   that, and you will see two options - INSERT and INSERT AS TEXT -
>   CHOOSE INSERT AS TEXT - and your HTML will appear within the Email box
>   !

Be aware that the HTML Outlook generates is at least as ugly as any of the auto-generated stuff from any Microsoft application.

Comment: I just tried this in Outlook 2010.  But it imported it as plain text, and so the HTML code appeared in the message window instead of the rendered HTML.  So it would appear that your trick is specific to 2007.

Comment: I just used it in Outlook 2010 pro and worked like a charm. I saved the file with a `.html` extension.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available anymore in Outlook 365: 
> "When you select the HTML file the INSERT button to the bottom right will activate - but to the right of the button there will be a down arrow, click on that, and you will see two options - INSERT and INSERT AS TEXT"

Answer (score 7):

You can install HTML Code Editor for Outlook.

http://outlookhtmleditor.codeplex.com/

You can download a installer on download tab. It'll allow you to import HTML file or edit HTML source code of your e-mail.

Comment: This extension is handy. It basically automates Nicole's suggestion, and allows you to edit the HTML without re-importing.

Comment: Pressing "Edit HTML Source" on the Advanced tab crashes my Outlook 2010.

Comment: This crash on OutLook 2013 :(