# Inside Outlook, with Outlook only, can I write my emails as HTML?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Inside Outlook, with Outlook only, is it possible to write my emails as HTML, instead of plain text?

I want to do it like that, so I don't have to use the Insert tab's buttons to insert things like links and tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit the HTML source code of an email in Outlook 2010 without any add-ins?](https://superuser.com/questions/536275/how-can-i-edit-the-html-source-code-of-an-email-in-outlook-2010-without-any-add)

Comment: Also see [How can I put a HTML code in Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/213825/how-can-i-put-a-html-code-in-outlook-2010)

Comment: What do you mean by "write my emails as HTML"? If you just want to compose new email in plain text, we can set this via File > Options > Mail > Compose message section. Select Plain Text in the option "Compose messages in this format:"

Comment: @Perry - As in, able to write in hyperlinks, which you can't do as plaintext, and also have to insert by button, it seems? Unlike how, like, on here, we can write hyperlinks with parentheses and brackets? TTYL.

Comment: It's true that we can still write hyperlinks in message body. A plain text file cannot have bold text, fonts, larger font sizes, or any other special text formatting. Do you mean that you want to block hyperlinks completely?

Comment: @Perry - No, I *want* to be able to make hyperlinks without the button.

Comment: What button do you mean? Just "text" hyperlinks, not clickable? In this case, I'm afraid this cannot be realized.

Comment: @Perry - Tell me how you make your hyperlinks?

Comment: What do you mean by "make" hyperlinks? I just paste a link to outlook email.

Comment: @Perry - Yes, and then it makes a hyperlink, whose displayed text you can edit? ... I want to skip the copy-paste step, and just type it in, and make it link.

Comment: Hi, I think I understand your requirement now. You want to automatically let the content become hyperlink. I did searched this but I'm afraid there is no built-in option to realize this.  Considering this, I'd like to recommend you submit a feedback to Outlook UserVoice: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: It is a place for customers to provide feedback about Outlook. What’s more, if an idea is high voted there by other customers, Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.